# std::unique_ptr in class, attempting to reference a deleted function error

Tags: c++, smart-pointers, stdvector

I'm trying to use smart pointer vector which is int type in a class, but it gives "attempting to refrence a deleted function" error:

```
class Object
    {
        public:
            std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int>> vec;
    };
```

When I create smart pointer in a function in same class(header file) or in another function, it doesn't give error

```
void test()
    {
        std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int>> vec;
    }
```

I think that problem can be about copying in vector because when I create just smart pointer without vector, it doesn't give error. To be honest, I couldn't try anything because I couldn't find anything to try. Thanks.

Comment: There's not enough code to see where the error happens, but be aware that having a member of type `unique_ptr` (or a container that contains `unique_ptr`) means that copy-assignment and copy-construction for that class will be `delete`d (of course, the same applies to any container that contains `unique_ptr`).

Comment: You need to show how you use `Object`. `std::unique_ptr` is not copyable, so if you try to make copies of an `Object` or its `vec`, it will fail to compile.

Comment: I don't do anything other than these codes. There is just main code which is empty.

Comment: @mehmetbilir The declaration in itself wouldn't throw that error, you must be calling the `delete`d methods somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone for answers, I solved problem. Surprisingly for me, it was about (dllexport) and (dllimport). I didn't know that they cause copying. I moved dll commands to inside of class, and prevent smart pointer vector has (dllexport) or (dllimport).